# azure mobile services error ECONNREFUSED every 2 mins

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-mobile-services

I've created a new azure mobile services with a new database 2 days ago, and all at a sudden, i'm getting

```
An unhandled exception occurred. Error: connect ECONNREFUSED
    at errnoException (net.js:770:11)
    at Object.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:761:19)
```

in the console. the service has no traffic yet, and i can't tell where this error is emmited from. 
Is there a way to intercept the http service on azure mobile serivces.

I've seen posts about node.js where they intercept with the code below but don't know how to do that on azure mobile services.

```
http.globalAgent.createConnection = function (options) {
  var socket = net.createConnection(options)
  socket.on('error', function (error) {
    errorCounter += 1;
    error.socketErrorId = errorCounter;
    console.log('socket error, while connecting to ', options.href, error);
  })
  return socket
}
```

PS. i'm aware of KUDU service which is accessible from https://anymobileservice.scm.azure-mobile.net/default.aspx

[console.log snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nXEfR.png)

Comment: This usually means that the connection to the database connection is failing. Double check your firewall rules and ensure that allow Azure services is enabled. 

Did you possibly enable SQL Auditing? SQL auditing currently isn't supported by Azure Mobile Services and will show as a database connection issue in the Mobile Service logs when auditing is turned on.

Comment: Have you use any custom Node.js modules?

Comment: gb92: not sure how to enable sql auditing. I used the default azure mobile services generated database. 
 Gary Liu - MSFT: I'm using stripe, winston-papertrail, winston, jsontoxml, xml, pubnub, twilio and braintree

Answer (score 0):

I create a scheduler script in frequency and test your custom modules one by one to reproduce your issue. And as in my test, it seems when I run a test example of `winston-papertrail` in the scheduler script, I can get the same error message with you.

It seems this module need to connect to its server on cloud to load the log template, which the request may be blocked by Azure mobile service as the outbound rules defined.

If you need some custom log requirements, you can try some other modules, and if you want to keep your log in files, you can consider to leverage Azure Storage.

And there is an approach to monitor your mobile service leveraging some 3rd part solutions. E.g, [New Relic & Windows Azure Mobile Services: End-to-End Monitoring for Your Mobile Apps](https://blog.newrelic.com/2013/06/28/new-relic-windows-azure-mobile-services-end-to-end-monitoring-for-your-mobile-apps/).

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately none of the solutions above resolved the issue, I added * to cors like another mobile service i have and still getting an error every few mins, will delete the mobile service and rebuild it again. Thanks anyway for the help.